# Class to define union of objects

Tags: java, oop, object, union

So.. I have this class, User, and any User has a set of Books and I want to define the class(es) and the hierarchy between this classes, so if I make the union between two Users, in the result, I want to have a new User, and his set of books will be the union between the Books from one User, and the books from the other.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is the question? What have you tried? Also, You should show some effort before saying "Give me the code"

Comment: i did some code, but i want to know what is the right way to do this, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply provide a static method within the `User` class, called `unionUser(User first, User second)` that takes two `User` instances as arguments and returns a new `User` instance with unioned `Book` sets, which will be accomplished by invoking the `Set#unionAll()` method.

```
 public class User {

    private Set<Book> books; //provide accessors

    ...
    public static User unionUser(User first, User second) {
      User result = new User();
      result.setBooks(first.getBooks().unionAll(second.getBooks());
      return result;
    }
    ...

 }
```

There will be no duplicates in the result `Book` set, because, as said in the Javadoc for the `java.util.Set` interface:

> A Set is a Collection that cannot contain duplicate elements. It
>   models the mathematical set abstraction.

Comment: thanks for your answer! can I make you another question? what if instead of having users and books, i have Users and groups of Users, and I want the union between user/user, user/groupofusers, group/group.. i explain myself? thanks again!

edit: now I have a class ElementoUsuario, and two classes that inherits from ElementoUsuario, they are Usuario and GrupoUsuarios..

Comment: Then, again you can use the `Set#unionAll()` method on user/user, user/groupofusers, etc. Read this article for clarification: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html
Cheers! :)

Comment: I will read it, thanks!

Comment: Make sure to implement equals() and hashCode() for both User and Book!

Answer (score 0):

Either make a method in user (returning a new user if they have a union, null otherwise) or pass two users to the constructor of user and let it create the union, the latter makes sense to me, the result of a union will be a new user regardless of whether they have common books (in OOP anyway).

But what have you tried? "The best" way is not always the best way for your application, if your idea is correct and the code doesn't work you are in the best possible situation to receive help here ;)